# Elegant Solution?

Tags: java, android, parallel-processing

**Elegant Solution**

Hey People.
I'm currently working on a Project and I am thinking of an elegant solution for the implementation, I'm tired of improvised solutions.

Let me try to explain my "Problem" to you:

The task of this part of my app is pretty simple:

I want my app to download some stuff and process that downloaded file in the background, displaying a ProgressDialog in the meantime. After that, the contents should be returned in a List of Strings which are displayed in some ListActivity. So far, not a big deal:

Downloader and the processing stuff is a subclassed AsyncTask and called in a class different from the main Activity. But now my Problem:

Where to call the Progressdialog? And how can the GUI-Thread "react" with a ProgressDialog? Should I call the ProgressDialog from the processing class or is it better to kind of "block" the main class, waiting for a notification?

Greetings

EnflamedSoul

Comment: Have you looked at a pattern called `Observer Pattern`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your progess dialog as a global variable.

```
ProgressDialog pd;
```

Where you are going to fire off the asyncTask:

```
showYourProgressDialog;
thread = new aThread().execute();
```

In your class:

```
public class aThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
            try {
                //Do your downloading and stuff
                                asyncHandler.sendMessage(asyncHandler.obtainMessage(0));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("1", "Error", e);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

Handler asyncHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            pd.dismiss();
            if (msg.what == 0) {
                //update what you need to               
            }           
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

blindstuffs anwser is going in the right direction, although I wouldn't use an Handler for handling the update progress. AsyncTask has his own functions to handle this, which are imho far easier to use and fit more into the AsyncTask class

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
    int count = urls.length;
    long totalSize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
        publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
    }
    return totalSize;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
    }
}
```

This example is taken from the [official Android SDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). The advantage of using `publishProgress` is that you can pass more than one value, depending on the number of arguments passed into doInBackground (i.e. if you're downloading more than 1 file).

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me. I screwed up something before, but I think now I got a pretty good solution. Thanks!